# Mac halts after boot and restarts

Tags: imac

My mac 2012 had black screen and fan yesterday. Then I powered off it and retried. This time it has loaded Catalina desktop and a few seconds later restarted.

Now when I ry to power on either it shows black screen with fan sound or it desktop, restarts.

I did NVRAM PRAM reset.

I tried pressing D on keyboard to diagnostics but it did not load diagnostics.

I tried recovery mode. It entered recovery mode but when in language selection halted and restarted.

I plan to unmount, then try unplug and plug some cables inside.

I appreciate any idea or suggestion.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If it’s crashing in Recovery, you have a hardware problem.  It could be memory or your hard drive. You didn’t indicate *which* 2012 Mac you had, but Zyou can start with booting to Internet Recovery (`Cmd-Opt-R`) if it fails there, try swapping out memory modules if possible. After that, you’ll need to take it in for service

Comment: Thank you very much Allan. My mac is late 2012 2544. I have tried internet recovery as advised. Progress bar came and it started loading but then suddenly restarted. Does it seem to be related to RAM? Due to current covid-19 issues I prevent going outside.

Comment: It’s an educated guess that’s its hardware. By booting Internet Recovery, you removed the drive from the equation as it loads the OS from the network, not the disk. The next thing to try is the memory. Remove one module and try to boot. If it fails put it back and remove the other and try again.  If it still fails, it’s the logic board